# Laplace transform and frames vs Bases

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, change-of-basis

The Laplace transform

$$F(s) = \int^{∞}_{0}f(t)e^{-st} dt$$ can be understood much like the fourier transform, as a change of basis of an $L^2$ function to the eigen functions of the differential operator $\frac{d}{dt}$

Unlike the complex exponentials, which form an uncountable orthogonal basis, the $e^{-st}$ basis functions are not in general orthogonal to each other. Does this mean we are switching to a frame and not a minimal orthogonal basis? Does this at all imply were overcounting? Or is there just redundant information in our resulting function?

Comment: I believe that "are in general orthogonal to each other" is a typo.  Do you mean "are not in general orthogonal to each other?"

Comment: @Brian Borchers fixed. Nice catch

Comment: There is, indeed, redundant information in the Laplace transform of a function.  To invert the Laplace transform, one only needs one vertical line of values in the complex plane (rather than all values in the complex plane).

Comment: @NicNic8 can you expand on this, or link to relevant readings somewhere? Thank you

Comment: @Craig  Look at equation 3 of Wikipedia here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform.  You only need one value of $\gamma$.

Comment: @NicNic8 this feels in some sense "natural" (not in the rigorous sense) since you send in data on the positive real line, you would only need that same amount of data to reverse it.

Comment: @Craig For sure!  I've been thinking about your question recently.  I don't think the Laplace transform is typically viewed as a change of basis (though I hope there is some way of interpreting it like this).  I think that it is typically seen as a trick for solving differential equations.  It's also used in control systems.

Comment: @Craig  If you'd like, I can write my understanding as an answer.  But then it will appear as though your question has been answered to other reviewers.

Comment: @NicNic8 OH! I see what I've been wondering about. This should mean that the inverse laplace transform is no unique right? In my original equation multiple $f(t)$ can give the same $F(s)$ correct?

Comment: @Craig The Laplace Transform is linear.  The Laplace Transform of a scalar multiple of a function equals the scalar multiple of the Laplace Transform of the function.

Comment: @NicNic8 I'm asking about the injective properties of the transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $L_0f = -if'$ is symmetric on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L_0)$ of functions $f\in L^2[0,\infty)$ that are absolutely continuous on $[0,\infty)$, that vanish at $0$, and that satisfy $f'\in L^2[0,\infty)$.  The operator $L_0$ is maximally symmetric, which means that it is closed and symmetric, but it is has no proper symmetric extension.

$L_0^*$ is not symmetric, but it is an extension of $L_0$. Indeed, $L_0^*f=-if'$ has the same domain except that the functions in the domain of $L_0^*$ do not necessarily vanish at $0$. The operator $L_0^*$ has spectrum equal to the upper half plane becase $e^{isx} \in L^2[0,\infty)$ for $\Im s > 0$ and $L_0^*e^{isx}=-i(-is e^{-isx})=se^{isx}$. The real axis is also in the spectrum because the spectrum is closed.

It is possible to extend the holomorphic functiona calculus to functions $F$ that are holomorphic on a neighborhood of the upper half plane:
$$
       F(L_0^*)f=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\epsilon-\infty}^{-i\epsilon+\infty}F(s)(s I -L_0^*)^{-1}fds.
$$
This extends to the case where $\epsilon=0$ if $F$ is a bounded holomorphic function in the upper half plane with a.e. boundary function $F(s)$ on the real axis. If you turn everything clockwise in the complex plane by looking at $L_0 f = -f'$ instead of $-if'$, then the operator calculus is implemented by a Fourier transform for the outer integral and a Laplace transform for the inner integral. The functional calculus allows for the computation of $F(L_0^*)f$ if $F$ is a bounded holomorphic function in the right half plane.